# Stratify dataset while also avoiding contamination by Index?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

As a reproducible example, I have the following data set:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = np.random.randint(0,20,size=(300, 5))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df = df.set_index(['ID'])

df.head()
Out: 
           A   B   C   D
ID                
12         3  14   4   7
9          5   9   8   4
12         18  17   3  14
1          0  10   1   0
9          10   5  11   9
```

I need to perform a 70%-30% stratified split (on y), which I know would look like this:

```
# Train/Test Split
X = df.iloc[:,0:-1] # Columns A, B, and C
y = df.iloc[:,-1] # Column D
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size = 0.70, test_size = 0.30, stratify = y)
```

However, although I want the training and testing sets to have the same (or similar enough) distribution of "D," I do not want the same "ID" to be present in both the testing and training.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:
A way to do (something like) what you asked could be to store the IDs by class, then for each class take 70% of IDs and insert samples with those IDs in Train, the rest in Test set.

Note this still does not guarantee the distributions are the same, if each ID has different number of occurrences. Moreover, given each ID can belong to multiple classes in D and should not be shared between *train* and *test* sets, seeking identical distributions becomes a complex optimisation problem. This is because each ID can only be included in either *train* or *test*, and at the same time adds to the assigned set a variable number of classes that depends on the classes the given ID has over all rows it occurs in.

A rather simpler way to split the data while approximating a balanced distribution is to iterate over the classes in random order and consider each ID only for one of the classes in its occurrences, therefore assigning it to *train*/*test* for all of its rows, hence removing it for future classes.

I find that considering the ID as a column helps for this task, so I changed your provided code as follows:

```
# Given snippet (modified)
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = np.random.randint(0,20,size=(300, 5))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

The proposed solution:

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

classes = df.D.unique().tolist() # get unique classes,
random.shuffle(classes)          # shuffle to eliminate positional biases
ids_by_class = defaultdict(list)


# iterate over classes
temp_df = df.copy()
for c in classes:
    c_rows = temp_df.loc[temp_df['D'] == c] # rows with given class
    ids = temp_df.ID.unique().tolist()      # IDs in these rows
    ids_by_class[c].extend(ids)

    # remove ids so they cannot be taken into account for other classes
    temp_df = temp_df[~temp_df.ID.isin(ids)]


# now construct ids split, class by class
train_ids, test_ids = [], []
for c, ids in ids_by_class.items():
    random.shuffle(ids) # shuffling can eliminate positional biases

    # split the IDs
    split = int(len(ids)*0.7) # split at 70%

    train_ids.extend(ids[:split])
    test_ids.extend(ids[split:])

# finally use the ids in train and test to get the
# data split from the original df
train = df.loc[df['ID'].isin(train_ids)]
test = df.loc[df['ID'].isin(test_ids)]
```

Let's test that the split ratio roughly conforms to 70/30, the data is preserved and no ID is shared between *train* and *test* dataframes:

```
# 1) check that elements in Train are roughly 70% and Test 30% of original df
print(f'Numbers of elements in train: {len(train)}, test: {len(test)}| Perfect split would be train: {int(len(df)*0.7)}, test: {int(len(df)*0.3)}')

# 2) check that concatenating Train and Test gives back the original df
train_test = pd.concat([train, test]).sort_values(by=['ID', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']) # concatenate dataframes into one, and sort
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']) # sort original df
assert train_test.equals(sorted_df) # check equality

# 3) check that the IDs are not shared between train/test sets
train_id_set = set(train.ID.unique().tolist())
test_id_set = set(test.ID.unique().tolist())
assert len(train_id_set.intersection(test_id_set)) == 0
```

Sample Outputs:

```
Numbers of elements in train: 209, test: 91| Perfect split would be train: 210, test: 90
Numbers of elements in train: 210, test: 90| Perfect split would be train: 210, test: 90
Numbers of elements in train: 227, test: 73| Perfect split would be train: 210, test: 90
```

Comment: So using your code, if I plot the distribution of y's: # Distributions 
bins = 30
plt.figure()
plt.hist(train.iloc[:,-1], bins, alpha=0.5, label='Train')
plt.hist(test.iloc[:,-1], bins, alpha=0.5, label='Test')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show() I see that the distributions are not close or similar, which is what "stratify" does and what I hope to have. However, I also want a row with ID '9' for example to not end up in both the training and the testing. Does that make sense?

Comment: Right, so my answer is completely out of place.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Do you have any idea why I get an empty "train" when I try your code?

Comment: Yes, sorry, there was an issue with "split = len(ids)//100 * 70", which rounded to 0 when len(ids) < 100. Anyhow I found one other issue with that approach, please check out my last edit. Hope it helps!